# Php include statement not working

Tags: php

I have tried include statement for my latest web project but it not working

```
<script src="Additionl Pages/mm_css_menu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Additionl Pages/Header.css" />

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<?php
include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\Header.html'); //header menu
?>
<?php
include('\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\Slideshow\slideshow.html'); //slideshow
?>
<?php
include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\logo.html');  //logo
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: next time, use `include_once`

Comment: please write error/exception you are getting

Comment: any error messages? what is the extension of the above file?

Comment: Use relative path and also the its not a good way to have project folder names with spaces in between.

Comment: did you get warning error?

Answer (score 2):

**Try placing your includes between your body tags like this:**
PS: you forgot the opening `html` tag, and your `script` and `link` tag go in-between your head tag. You also forgot the `C:\` in your second include. I have fixed it below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <script src="Additionl Pages/mm_css_menu.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Additionl Pages/Header.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\Header.html'); //header menu
        ?>
        <?php
        include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\Slideshow\slideshow.html'); //slideshow
        ?>
        <?php
        include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\logo.html');  //logo
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Also there is no need to have multiple php tags. You can do the same thing above in one php tag like this:

```
<?php
    include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\Header.html'); //header menu
    include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\Slideshow\slideshow.html'); //slideshow
    include('C:\wamp\www\Bank web\Additionl Pages\logo.html');  //logo
?>
```

Comment: I'd go the extra mile and put the first two lines in the `<head>` block too. Oh, and add `<html>`

Comment: 2nd include statement missing C:\

Comment: First of all he doesn't need to start and close php brackets for each include, secondly `logo.html` seems really horrible from it's name, third, path looks dirty to me

Comment: @SumitBijvani you are right but i don't want to edit it too much. I want op to see what he has been missing.

Comment: @vidhu you need to explain this to OP.

Comment: @SumitBijvani i did. I wrote "Try placing your includes between your body tags like this:"

Comment: @vidhu also add comment like there is no need to add multiple `<?php `blocks for each include statement...